# Visual Studio Task-List during TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

In Visual Studio one can create Comments like: `//TODO Fix the foo(bar)` and show them in the Task List Window. Even with other Token Words instead of TODO.

Is there a Way to show such a Task List, or the count of //TODO, in a TFS Build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the VS feature, and there is no command to show this task list, so TFS can not show such a Task List.

Comment: So there is no extension, which adds a task for the build, to count the "//TODO"?

Comment: I never see such an extension.:(

Comment: I would create an analyzer for tasks like this. And then refer it in VS or TFS build. Good starting point: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers

Comment: @sam Thanks, I will have a look at that. :)